# SSRS Set Date/Time parameter to NULL based on previous date parameter's selection

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have three date parameters(all three are picked using calender) on my report: Inforce date, StartDate, EndDate. The requirement is to either have the user select Inforce date (or) start and end date.
***If Inforce date is selected, Start and end date should be Null(also grey out) and vice versa.***
 I was not able to acheive this. I tried using a dataset, default and available values. The problem I face is that the moment I set the start date/End date to Null, the datepicker changes to dropdown.  Please help me in resolving this issue.
 --Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SSRS 2008 doesn't support enabling/disabling parameters at run-time. You could use [cascading parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169.aspx) and have the Start/End dates display a list of dates to select (or vice versa with Inforce date), but you'll lose the calendar control, since cascading parameters only support drop-downs.